# Malloc/"ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code"

Tags: c, gcc, malloc

Im using a linked list to store data about costumers:

```
typedef struct{
    char* name;
    unsigned long number;
    char package;
}Client;


struct node {
    Client value;
    struct node *next;
};
typedef struct node *LinkedListNode;
```

The compiler now complains about mixed declarations and code when I declare the head of the list in the main function:

```
int main(){

    LinkedListNode head;
    head = (LinkedListNode) malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    Client aux,aux2;
    char command;
    command= getchar();
    while(command!='x'){ 
        switch(command){
                    (...)
```

I can see what the problem is, since I only got this error after adding the "malloc" call.I just dont know how to fix it

The stuctures are defined in a *.h file, in case that matters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To fix it you must move all your variable declarations to the top of the block in which they appear. The declarations of your variables must all appear before the first non-declaring code.

For instance:

```
int main(void)
{
    LinkedListNode head;
    Client aux,aux2;
    char command;

    head = (LinkedListNode) malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    command= getchar();
    while(command!='x'){ 
        switch(command){
                    (...)
}
```

As an alternative, you could introduce a new block using braces, inside the function and declare your variables at the top of that block. However, that may result in rather artificial and messy code.

This particular rule was changed in C99. Your code would be valid under C99.